# How to change the PDF reader on Chome from Preview to Acrobat Reader on MacBook?

Tags: google-chrome, preview, adobe, chrome-extensions

How can I change the PDF reader on Chrome from Preview to Acrobat Reader on MacBook? The Adobe program is much more versatile and I prefer that one to Preview. In my Plug-ins in Chrome the Adobe Acrobat has the option to be de-activated as if it is the program I am using now. But my Chrome automatically opens PDFs with Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Open Chrome and type "chrome://plugins" into the address bar at the top.

Step 2: Scroll down and find Chrome PDF Viewer.

Step 3: Click the "Disable" link to prevent PDFs from loading within Chrome.

Step 4: Click the "Enable" link on Adobe PDF plugin.